# Run Python Function Every Second for A Minute

Tags: python, mysql, function, loops, timer

I recently started learning Python and I have an application for it where I would like to create a text file that records data every two seconds for a minute, and then begins again with a new file. I have it written where the opened file is formatted for SQL and SQL INSERT queries are being added on.

The trouble I am having is creating the code to actually work properly. The Python itself is working fine for just inserting a new line of SQL to the already opened file, but the output looks like this:

```
[blank line is here because of the \n]
INSERT INTO table (column 1, column 2) VALUES ('7113', '1337');
INSERT INTO table (column 1, column 2) VALUES ('7113', '1337');
```

My issue is that I need to get the data so there is no new line at the top and no semicolon at the last row.

**This is my source:**

```
from threading import Timer
import time

def start():
    t = Timer(1.0,start)

    foo = "7113"
    bar = "1337"
    date = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    sql = "\nINSERT INTO table (column 1, column 2) VALUES ('%s', '%s');" % (foo, bar)

    query = open(date + ".sql", "a")
    query.write(sql)
    query.close()
    t.start()

start()
```

Since I'm not the best with language, a simpler version of what I want to do is:

1. Have one function run the first code, spitting out `INSERT INTO table (column 1, column 2) VALUES ('7113', '1337');` without the extra line in front but with a semicolon.
2. Have another function run 58 times, adding lines with `\n` before the SQL query and the semicolon after.
3. Have the last function run the 60th time, including the `\n` but without the semicolon.
4. Close the current file and generate a new text file with the timestamp just for that minute, like `2013-07-09 12-30-00.sql` and repeat the process over again for `2013-07-09 12-31-00.sql`, and so on.

I imagine there is a lot more after that, like getting a PHP or Python script to read the date and execute it, or I could just have all of them executed and then order the table ascending. However, that can be solved and researched at a later date. I just want to get this working since I've been searching for a few hours now on how to do it and I couldn't find anything helpful. I'm sure the answer is something obvious, though.

Thanks for reading and I hope you guys can help! I've used this website a bunch now for helpful tidbits and it's fantastic. Whoever came up with this needs to be praised a bunch.

Also, if anyone has any useful resources for learning Python (I learned through [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/)), I would really appreciate them. This is so much more fun than learning C++.

Comment: Why do you need different behavior on the first and last lines? Why not just end every line with a semicolon and a newline?

Comment: I thought you can't do that in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by having a `global counting` variable and using `if` and `elif` statements. Currently the script is functioning every 500ms with no problem. If anyone wants to see my code, here it is:

[Commented version because syntax highlighting here with comments is screwing up for whatever reason.](http://pastebin.com/2iJhkzHA)

```
from threading import Timer
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib
import time

datetime = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H.%M')
filename = datetime + ".sql"
url = "localhost/send.cgi"
interval = 0.5
table_name = "0001"
columns = "(time, foo, bar)"
counting = 0 

def parser():
    t = Timer(interval, parser)
    global counting
    global filename
    query = open(filename, "a")

    if counting == 0:
        date = int(time.time()*1000)
        web = urllib.urlopen(url)
        tree = ET.parse(web)
        root = tree.getroot()
        foo = root[1].text.replace(" ", "")
        bar = root[2].text.replace(" ", "")
        sql = "INSERT INTO %s %s VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s');" % (table_name, columns, date, foo, bar)
        counting += 1
        query.write(sql)
        print counting
        t.start()
    elif (counting > 0) and (counting < 59):
        date = int(time.time()*1000)
        web = urllib.urlopen(url)
        tree = ET.parse(web)
        root = tree.getroot()
        foo = root[1].text.replace(" ", "")
        bar = root[2].text.replace(" ", "")
        sql = "\nINSERT INTO %s %s VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s');" % (table_name, columns, date, foo, bar)
        counting += 1
        query.write(sql)
        print counting
        t.start()
    elif counting == 59:
        date = int(time.time()*1000)
        web = urllib.urlopen(url)
        tree = ET.parse(web)
        root = tree.getroot()
        foo = root[1].text.replace(" ", "")
        bar = root[2].text.replace(" ", "")
        sql = "\nINSERT INTO %s %s VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')" % (table_name, columns, date, foo, bar)
        counting += 1
        query.write(sql)
        print counting
        t.start()
    elif counting == 60:
        query.close()
        datetime = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M')
        filename = datetime + ".sql"
        counting = 0
        t.start()
parser()
```

If any improvements can be made, I would love to see them! <3 This code is meant for a certain kind of web server, though. It may require some modifications to work. What the web server does is, when requested, sends a virtual XML file (which is just data, not the file) and this code requests it, interprets it, and shoots it into a .sql file so I can later execute them into a table to something. In the end, the code will grab over ten different columns of data and create the file for an hour, which is 7200 half-seconds.

Enjoy!

EDIT: Yay, apparently the SQL syntax doesn't work. Troubleshooting.